# Finding values in JSON type response (HTTP) in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a json response

```json
{"length": 2, "chain": [{"index": 0, "transactions": [], "timestamp": 0, "previous_hash": "0", "nonce": 0, "hash": "6dbf23122cb5046cc5c0c1b245c75f8e43c59ca8ffeac292715e5078e631d0c9"}, {"index"
: 1, "transactions": [{"test": "test2.m4a", "ipfs_hash": "QmaQgbSbgZdAfdiHmnfD9PevwpYSepytvA5G6agupqjVA3", "timestamp": 1610467381.102983, "Mac_ADD": "e0:94:67:bc:17:f9", "signature": "b'AQAgIQgAAD'"}], "timestamp":1610467386.9993732,"previous_hash":"6dbf23122cb5046cc5c0c1b245c75f8e43c59ca8ffeac292715e5078e631d0c9", "nonce": 214, "hash": "00a92715e60f577a57165b52c02e2b6bbef1ba60a3a27ead16e4d6a7a0a9d3d2"}], "peers": []}
```

I want to find the corresponding "ipfs_hash" using the "test" value. How do I achieve this in python?

Comment: Hi you should post the code you have already developed here so people can help - a starting point in Python would be to parse the JSON string using [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have mentioned, you can use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to load your string into a python object, e.g., a dictionary.

```py
s = '''{"length": 2, "chain": [{"index": 0, "transactions": [], "timestamp": 0, "previous_hash": "0", "nonce": 0, "hash": "6dbf23122cb5046cc5c0c1b245c75f8e43c59ca8ffeac292715e5078e631d0c9"}, {"index"
: 1, "transactions": [{"test": "test2.m4a", "ipfs_hash": "QmaQgbSbgZdAfdiHmnfD9PevwpYSepytvA5G6agupqjVA3", "timestamp": 1610467381.102983, "Mac_ADD": "e0:94:67:bc:17:f9", "signature": "b'AQAgIQgAAD'"}], "timestamp":1610467386.9993732,"previous_hash":"6dbf23122cb5046cc5c0c1b245c75f8e43c59ca8ffeac292715e5078e631d0c9", "nonce": 214, "hash": "00a92715e60f577a57165b52c02e2b6bbef1ba60a3a27ead16e4d6a7a0a9d3d2"}], "peers": []}'''

import json

d = json.loads(s)

test = 'test2.m4a'
for c in d['chain']:
    for t in c['transactions']:
        if t['test'] == test:
            print(t['ipfs_hash'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python standard library module `json` to convert JSON strings into dictionaries by using the `json.loads(json_string)` function.

For example:

```
import json
my_dictionary = json.loads("""{"length": 2, "chain": [{"index": 0, "transactions": [], "timestamp": 0, "previous_hash": "0", "nonce": 0, "hash": "6dbf23122cb5046cc5c0c1b245c75f8e43c59ca8ffeac292715e5078e631d0c9"}, {"index" : 1, "transactions": [{"test": "test2.m4a", "ipfs_hash": "QmaQgbSbgZdAfdiHmnfD9PevwpYSepytvA5G6agupqjVA3", "timestamp": 1610467381.102983, "Mac_ADD": "e0:94:67:bc:17:f9", "signature": "b'AQAgIQgAAD'"}], "timestamp":1610467386.9993732,"previous_hash":"6dbf23122cb5046cc5c0c1b245c75f8e43c59ca8ffeac292715e5078e631d0c9", "nonce": 214, "hash": "00a92715e60f577a57165b52c02e2b6bbef1ba60a3a27ead16e4d6a7a0a9d3d2"}], "peers": []}""")
```

Once you have it as a dictionary, you can access any of the elements by indexing with the key like so:

```
print(my_dictionary["length"])
print(my_dictionary["transactions"])
```

Comment: I have tried something similar    
'url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/chain'
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    print(data['transactions']) '
but I get a error noting KeyError: 'transactions'

Comment: If you're getting a KeyError, then it is most likely that the data in the variable `r` is not what you think it is. Maybe you got an error back when requesting the webpage?

Comment: There was no error in the webpage ,I printed out the data and it is correct , I checked the type of `data` and it returned `dict`.

Comment: I think requests.get() does not return the json response directly; it returns a dictionary with other information too like the status code. You will have to find which key your response is under in `data` and look for `transactions` in *that*.